# XPC communication between service and client app works only when launched from xcode

Tags: xcode, xpc

XPC communication works fine when I launch the targets from my Xcode. But, when I manually launch the service and client apps by double clicking them on the icons, the connection invalidation message shows up.Whay do they work fine inside xcode and not from outside ?.What magic is Xcode doing here to make the communication work.

Comment: I seem to be having a similar problem. Did you eventually find the root cause?

Comment: Yes, I copied the XPC info plist from the xcode project to /System/Library/LaunchDaemons. when outside xcode, to launch the app, I had to use launchctl. ex: launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/<xpc-info-plist>

Comment: so you were not able to launch XPC from XCode?

Answer (score 1):

For all folks, who met the same problem using `xpc_connection_create_mach_service`: XPC works through a lot of launchd stuff; when we are debugging the app in xCode, it mediates the app and launchd connection, but without xCode we need to do it ourselves.

To get this alive, the one should start it through launchd using the launch plist file.
There is an example of such plist [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), but it's not enough.
The trick is the `MachServices` key, which looks like:

```
<key>MachServices</key>
<dict>
<key>com.server.bundle-id</key>
<true/>
</dict>
```

This is the way we are creating the mach service, so I guess our XPC connection may have some mach port below it.